# UITextField does not detect changes with 'swipe to type'

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a textfield with a attributed target which is supposed to detect for changes to the textfield label, and then run a function. However, the `.editingChanged` UIControl event is not triggered when a user swipes to type (on the keyboard); this also happens when a email or password is autofilled.

**My code:**

```
let textField: UITextField = {
    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.backgroundColor = .clear
    textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .medium)
    textField.textColor = .label
    textField.placeholder = ""
    return textField
}()
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    print(textField.text)
}
```

Comment: you just need the updated text after swipe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried including `textField.sendActions(for: .editingChanged)`?

It's also possible that `textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String)` might be returning false?